# jquery prevent other link toggling

Tags: jquery, toggle

i made a simple toggling like that:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tog1").click(function(){
        $("#rel1").slideToggle();
  })

$("#tog2").click(function(){
        $("#rel2").slideToggle();
  })

......

})
<script>

<ul>
<li><a id="tog1" href="#">اتصل بالعضو</a></li>
<li><a id="tog2" href="#">أعماله السابقه</a></li>
<li><a id="tog3" href="#">مواضيع العضو</a></li>
<li><a id="tog4" href="#">ردود العضو </a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="rel1"></div>
<div id="rel2"></div>
<div id="rel3"></div>
<div id="rel4"></div>
```

i want to prevent or disable other links toggling when i press one and allow only for one link to be toggled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIrst, I would add a class and a [`data-`](http://api.jquery.com/data) attribute to all those links:

```
<li><a id="tog1" class="tog" data-rel="rel1" href="#">اتصل بالعضو</a></li>
```

Now we can make one click handler for them all. Extract the div's ID from `this`, and close its [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) when you open it:

```
$(".tog").click(function(){
    var $div = $('#'+$(this).data('rel'));
    $div.slideToggle().siblings('div').slideUp();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/HVNbB/